# Why does Tensorflow 2 give a warning (but still work anyway) when the input is a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

On Tensorflow 2.0, whenever I pass a Pandas DataFrame as the input, then Tensorflow works fine but prints out a warning `WARNING:tensorflow:Falling back from v2 loop because of error: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, <class 'NoneType'>`.  I don't recall ever getting that error with TF 1.x so this must be new. But why is it a warning?

I understand what it's asking for, and yes, converting that DataFrame to a pure numpy array does make the error go away. But why does TF care? Despite the warning, it's clearly able to work fine with a DataFrame. Scikit-learn also expects a numpy array, yet that works fine when you pass a DataFrame. TF 1.x worked fine with a DataFrame too. Pandas is incredibly common, so why does TF 2.0 pretend it can't handle it (even though it clearly can)?  Is it just an efficiency thing where TF didn't want to pay the cost of converting that DataFrame to a TF.DataSet? But TF is now asking me to do that conversion instead, so how is that anymore efficient than just letting TF do the conversion itself? (and besides, surely the overhead of converting pandas input a single time at the start is negligible compared to the billions of multiplications during training?)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#Make some fake data
df = pd.DataFrame()
NUM_ROWS = 1000
NUM_FEATURES = 50
random_data = np.random.normal(size=(NUM_ROWS, NUM_FEATURES))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=random_data, columns=['x_' + str(ii) for ii in range(NUM_FEATURES)])
y = df.sum(axis=1) + np.random.normal(size=(NUM_ROWS))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, input_dim=df.shape[1], activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
        ])
NUM_EPOCHS = 500

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error');
hist = model.fit(df, y, epochs=1, verbose=0) ###This gives the warning (but still works fine anyway)
```

What is the purpose of that warning?

Comment: I have the same issue and if I run the same code in TF 2.1 it crashes and burns... At least when I feed it Pandas it will run. If I convert everything with .to_numpy() it also crashes and burns in TF 2.0

Comment: AHA! It looks like EarlyStopping monitor isn't compatible with eager execution.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate your issue in `TF 2.0` and it is fixed in the commit, [617f788](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/617f788da56c98c46ee346e8b2e7bf1e061bb3e1#diff-f8dd40712ac721c1b363e1a1ec44c1a3) on Nov 23 2019 in **Tensorflow Version 2.1**

So, please upgrade your `Tensorflow` version to either `2.1` or `2.2` and the issue will be resolved.

Working code is mentioned below:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.2.0

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print(tf.__version__)

#Make some fake data
df = pd.DataFrame()
NUM_ROWS = 1000
NUM_FEATURES = 50
random_data = np.random.normal(size=(NUM_ROWS, NUM_FEATURES))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=random_data, columns=['x_' + str(ii) for ii in range(NUM_FEATURES)])
y = df.sum(axis=1) + np.random.normal(size=(NUM_ROWS))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, input_dim=df.shape[1], activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
        ])
NUM_EPOCHS = 500

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

hist = model.fit(df, y, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

Output:

```
2.2.0
Train on 1000 samples
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 411us/sample - loss: 49.0524
```

If you observe the output warning no longer appears.