# Tensorflow error when defining sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to define a sequential model for  a program that analyses text reviews using sentiment analysis. I am having trouble however when defining one of the models I am trying to use.

Below is the section of my code (with the relevant imports) I am having problems with:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=42)
n_features = X_train.shape[1] 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',
input_shape=(n_features,)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

loss, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test Accuracy: %.3f' % (acc * 100))
```

Below is the warning message that I am receiving:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Falling back from v2 loop because of error: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>, <class 'NoneType'>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Falling back from v2 loop because of error: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>, <class 'NoneType'>

> Test Accuracy: 78.668

As you can see I am still receiving the accuracy for the model but also the warning. This is the first time creating something like this so I am a little confused and any help would be much appreciated. I am programming in Python and I am using a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: As you may have noticed, it's a warning, not an error. I would suggest you try reformating the code as follows: `import tensorflow as tf` and then `model = tf.keras.Sequential()`

Comment: I have done this like you say however I am still receiving the warning message

Comment: Are your input data array or matrix data types?

Comment: What is your tensorflow version (`tf.__version__`)? Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62216951/9987623) answer on the same issue?

Comment: Import models with: from keras.models import Sequential

Comment: Or even: from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

Comment: I added the line of code "tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR') " and this hides the warning message from the output however I'm not sure if this is a viable solution. How do I check what type the input data is?